# Site searching with jQuery + HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I've been trying to make a page where you type in a topic, like language, and then the `div` with an id of `language` pops up. I want it to hide first. It doesn't work, however. Here's a snippet:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
div.content { display: none; }
</style>
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="" />
<button id="searchbtn">Search</button>
<hr/>

<div id="main"></div>

<div class="content">
<div id="language">testy - it works!!</div>
</div>

<script>
var portals = ["language", "constructedlanguages"];
var searchterm, id;

function randPortal(array) {
return array[Math.floor((Math.random()*array.length))];
}

$("#search").attr("placeholder", "e.g. " + randPortal(portals));
$("#searchbtn").click(function() {
searchterm = $("#search").val();
id = "#" + searchterm;
if (portals.indexOf(searchterm) != -1) {
$("#main").html() = $(id).html();
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: instead of rewriting the html element, use the [add function](https://api.jquery.com/add/) to add html to the main element

Comment: @Thundter I tried `$("#main").add($(id).html());` but it still didn't do anything. Or am I doing it incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here `$("#main").html() = $(id).html();`, you are assigning HTML content incorrectly.

So you should fix like this

```
$("#main").html($(id).html());
```

```js
var portals = ["language", "constructedlanguages"];
var searchterm, id;

function randPortal(array) {
    return array[Math.floor((Math.random()*array.length))];
}

$("#search").attr("placeholder", "e.g. " + randPortal(portals));

$("#searchbtn").click(function() {
      searchterm = $("#search").val();
      id = "#" + searchterm;
      if (portals.indexOf(searchterm) != -1) {
         $("#main").html($(id).html());
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
div.content { display: none; }
</style>
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="" />
<button id="searchbtn">Search</button>
<hr/>

<div id="main"></div>

<div class="content">
<div id="language">testy - it works!!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, um, looks like I could study up on my jQuery :)